# After removing Fglrx and ati drivers cannot login

Tags: ati, kubuntu, fglrx

I was running kubuntu 10.10 with ati drivers (11-5). For some [problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47193/kubuntu-kde-restart-when-click-on-program-icon-on-task-manager-or-with-altta), i re-installed ati-drivers to install lastest version (11-6) but before install the new driver I reinstalled Fglrx as described [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem:__Need_to_fully_remove_-fglrx_and_reinstall_-ati_from_scratch) then rebooted. Now when I start my computer it boots up and later show kubuntu progress bar then fade off with random colors and goes black completely.

How can I fix this without needing to reinstall the whole system?

Comment: if you won't be doing any 3D stuff, like games or modeling, you can use the RadeonHD Open source drivers.

Answer (score 2):

*From the author, who placed the answer in his post rather than as a new answer*

I booted from a live cd and mounted my linux partion. Then chroot and finally installed ATI drivers. This fixed the problem for me.